# insert element at the beginning of std::forward_list

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, forward-list

I want to remove element from `std::forward_list` and insert it to the beginning of list 
But there is no insert method ... It just has `insert_after` !

How can I  insert element at the beginning of `std::forward_list` ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/push_front/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method 
`push_front`

to insert an element at the beginning of the list

Another approach is to use method `insert_after`.

Here is an example of using the both methods

```
std::forward_list<int> l;

l.push_front( 1 );
l.insert_after( l.cbefore_begin(), 0 );

for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`std::forward_list::push_front`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/push_front/).

Example:

```
// forward_list::push_front
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  forward_list<int> mylist = {77, 2, 16};
  mylist.push_front (19);
  mylist.push_front (34);

  std::cout << "mylist contains:";
  for (int& x: mylist) std::cout << ' ' << x;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output: mylist contains: `34 19 77 2 16`